# Concerns with Frequent Updates in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to maintain near real-time digital twins of IoT devices.  Some research has pointed to [Eclipse's Ditto framework](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/) built on top of a MongoDB database.   Being unfamiliar with database systems, I am concerned about the practicality of using Mongo (or something similar) for frequent updates to fields of each digital twin model.  For reference, imagine telemetry (like position & temperature) updates every second from 1000 devices.

Obviously the database can handle this bandwidth of activity, but does it impose abnormal strain on the physical disk or other systems?  Also, is this outside of the feasible use cases of this database model (is MongoDB a tool for the job)?  My searches have yielded poor answers to both of these questions.

Answer (score 1):

If DB system is designed (and build) to handle that load of X inserts per second, it won't impose abnormal strain on physical hardware. Hardware is built to handle it.

When you are building your MongoDB, remember that MongoDB likes memory over CPU-power (ie. More memory makes Mongo faster than more CPU) and a fast disk (higher IOPS) is always better than a slow one.

If there is a huge amount of read and write traffic, sharding (clustering; remember to select good sharding-key) data makes load to the single replica set lower.